# How to update input fields with dataset values?

Tags: javascript, forms, input, drop-down-menu, dataset

I cannot figure out what I am missing ... I am trying to do a task that has been done before (change `<input>` values on `<select>` change), but I cannot see where my code is failing.

Then I am creating my dropdown menu from a separate woocommerce-based command where I am using `datasets` to store the values; I want to use these values in two associated inputs.

```
echo '<p><select id="product" name="product" onchange="change_details(this.value)">';
    echo '<option>-- Select SKU--</option>';
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
  global $product;
    $sku = $product->get_sku();
    echo '<option value=' . $sku . ' data-sales=' . $results[$sku]['sales'] .' data-token=' .$results[$sku]['token'] . '>' . $sku . ' </option>';
  endwhile;
echo '</select>';
```

Here is where I want to update two input fields to have these `sales` and `token` values:

```
echo '<p><input type="text" placeholder="sales" id="sales" name="sales" size="20" /></p>'; 
echo '<p><input type="text" placeholder="e.g. token" id="token" name="token" size="20" /></p>';
```

and lastly, my javascript for the onchange function;

```
function change_details(){
        document.getElementById("sales").dataset.sales;
        document.getElementById("token").dataset.token;
}
```

Comment: Java is not javascript.   What is the last point of success? In other words, where is the earliest point of failure? You are mixing procedural and object-oriented syntax.

Comment: @mickmackusa I have edited my question to reflect your java statement. I believe the earliest point of failure resides in the dropdown menu where I store the data (in data-sales or data-token) or my javascript. I did test with `document.getElementById("sales").value=test;` and it would work, but upon changing to my arrayed values, it seems to have messed it up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something is not working with the StackOverflow javascript snippet builder...

```
function change_details(obj){
  document.getElementById("sales").value = obj.options[obj.selectedIndex].dataset.sales;
  document.getElementById("token").value = obj.options[obj.selectedIndex].dataset.token;
}
```

```html
<select onchange="change_details(this);">
  <option value="sku1" data-sales="sku_sales1" data-token="sku_token1">skuA</option>
  <option value="sku2" data-sales="sku_sales2" data-token="sku_token2">skuB</option>
  <option value="sku3" data-sales="sku_sales3" data-token="sku_token3">skuC</option>
  <option value="sku4" data-sales="sku_sales4" data-token="sku_token4">skuD</option>
</select>

<input type="text" placeholder="sales" id="sales" name="sales" size="20" />

<input type="text" placeholder="e.g. token" id="token" name="token" size="20" />
```

Pass the select element object to your function, then use pure javascript to isolate the selected option, then set the input values using the dataset values.

https://jsfiddle.net/7b51f38t/12/

Your javascript function wasn't actually "doing anything".

Comment: Ah man, this works like a charm. My value for the javascript was unset. thank you for saving me from another sleepless night!